# How do you make a directory in C++ on UNIX (OSX)?

Tags: c++, unix

I've spent quite a bit of time on Google trying to find an answer for this but to no avail. I found ways to create text files by just opening nonexistent files to autocreate. However, I'm still unclear as to how to create a directory for example on my Desktop.

I got this code, and it runs successfully, but I'm not sure if I'm actually making any directories. It seems that I opened terminal using system and then run the command (mkdir A%d).

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    char command[50];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        sprintf(command,"mkdir A%d",i);
        system(command);}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use mkdir, the system call.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int mkdir(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
```

So, to do what you are doing, you would do something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << "A" << i;
   int rc = mkdir(ss.str().c_str(), 0777);
   if(rc == 0) std::cout << "Created " << ss.str() << " success\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm getting an error with the code you provided: Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::basic_stringstream<char,std::__1::char_traits<char>,std::__1::allocator......

Any additional help is appreciated.

Comment: probably missing `#include <sstream>`